# SQL Server: How do I get the value for the row I inserted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scope-identity

My SQL Server table has, between other, these columns.

**AutoID** which has IdentitySpecification set to True and **GuidKey** which has the default value of (newid())

```
AutoID   GuidKey
1        f4rc-erdd
2        gedd-rrds
```

Is there any way of getting the GuidKey from the row inserted?

I need something like the Scope_Identity(), with the difference that i don't want to get the content of AutoID, but the GuidKey column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sql Server 2005/2008

```
INSERT INTO myTable (SomeColumn)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.GuidKEY
VALUES ('SomeData')
```

Comment: What if you have more than one column that stores a guid value?

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
 SELECT GuidKEy FROM [Table] WHERE AutoID= scope_identity()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (GuidKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO YourTable(Columns) 
  OUTPUT INSERTED.GuidKey INTO @TempTable(GuidKey) 
  VALUES(YourVALUES)
```

This will insert the inserted GuidKey into @TempTable. You can then pull the value from that table.

Answer (score 0):

For the `uniqueidentifier` i do as follows:

```
DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier
SET @ID = newId()

...
```

Then i use the `@ID` in my insert statement. Finally i return the value using `SELECT @ID` or `RETURN @ID`